# Como enviar emails com PHPmailer em localhost sem module ssl

Tags: phpmailer, localhost

Olá pessoal gostaria de saber se existe a possibilidade de enviar email localhost usando a biblioteca PHPmailer sem ter que instalar o module SSL no apache e PHP? Já tentei diversas técnicas mas até agora para todas é necessário o SSL instalado.

Comment: Olá José, bem-vindo! Por favor separa a pergunta e a solução. Coloca a solução como resposta, clicando no botão aqui em baixo para responder.

Comment: Estou votando para fechar esta pergunta como fora de escopo porque isso não é uma perguinta, é uma postagem, que não confere com o propósito do SO.

Comment: Tópico alterado para se enquadrar no escopo

Comment: Neste site não adicionamos RESOLVIDO no titulo. Se a pergunta não estivesse fechada, o correto seria postar a solução e aceitá-la em seguida.

Comment: [Como responder às próprias perguntas](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: Consegui responder. É que enquanto estava com pendência a opção para responder estava desabilitada.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui, em fim, enviar email com a classe phpmailer, em localhost, sem a necesidade de instalar ssl na máquina. Essa dica foi testada agora em janeiro de 2017.

Para poder enviar email com phpmailer localmente, basta, editar o arquivo '**class.smtp.php**' e, logo após a linha:

```
public function connect($host, $port = null, $timeout = 30, $options = array()){
static $streamok;
    //This is enabled by default since 5.0.0 but some providers disable it
    //Check this once and cache the result
```

inserir o código:

```
if (count($options) == 0){
  $options['ssl'] = array('verify_peer' => false, 'verify_peer_name' => false, 'allow_self_signed' => true);
}
```

espero ter ajudado!!